# Using puppet classes in modules

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

I'm still fairly new to puppet, and am now at the point where I want to use classes with parameters in my custom modules.

I have a module called tsvpuppet, and I want it to act as a wrapper to the mysql module
with standard paramters (maybe later on based on custom facts fromt he host).

in my `/etc/puppet/modules/tsvmysql/manifests/init.pp` file

```
class tsvmysql {
     class { '::mysql::server':
            root_password    => 'password',
            override_options => $override_options
           }
}
```

The above module code seems to work, but classes in classes just feels wrong.

Can anyone suggest a better way of writing this, or suggest how it *should* be done ?

Many thanks.

Matt

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with that. if you are going to instantiate a class in puppet you either do what you did, `class {}` syntax, or `include ::mysql::server` syntax. If you use the `include` syntax you cannot pass parameters to it without using `hiera`. `include` can be slightly safer since if it is included already in another class it won't do anything. `class {}` syntax will bomb out if it exists somewhere else.

Comment: Thankyou, that explains why I couldn't see how to use include with paramters. As most of the paramters will be coming from custom facts I have written, I think I'll need to stick with multiple classes, and a single include as below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the class `::mysql::server`.

```
class tsvmysql {
   include '::mysql::server'
}

class { '::mysql::server':
            root_password    => 'password',
            override_options => $override_options
}
```

Comment: I really like this, it makes sense, and fits in perfectly with what i'm trying to achieve. Many thanks!